# How to filter dataframe based on varying thresholds for indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame and a dictionary like this:

```
thresholds = {'column':{'A':10,'B':11,'C':9}}

df:
    Column
A     13
A     7
A     11
B     12
B     14
B     14
C     7
C     8
C     11
```

For every index group, I want to calculate the count of values less than the threshold and greater than the threshold value.
So my output looks like this:

```
df:
    Values<Thr  Values>Thr
A       1          2
B       0          3
C       2          1
```

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Are you doing this for more than one column?

Comment: @It_is_Chris Yes, but the final output is separate for every column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np

t = df.index.to_series().map(thresholds['column'])

out = (pd.crosstab(df.index, np.where(df['Column'].gt(t), 'Values>Thr', 'Values≤Thr'))
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
       )
```

Output:

```
   Values>Thr  Values≤Thr
A           2           1
B           3           0
C           1           2
```

##### syntax variant

```
out = (pd.crosstab(df.index, df['Column'].gt(t))
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
         .rename(columns={False: 'Values≤Thr', True: 'Values>Thr'})
      )
```

#### apply on many column based on the key in the dictionary

```
def count(s):
    t = s.index.to_series().map(thresholds.get(s.name, {}))
    return (pd.crosstab(s.index, s.gt(t))
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
         .rename(columns={False: 'Values≤Thr', True: 'Values>Thr'})
      )

out = pd.concat({c: count(df[c]) for c in df})
```

*NB. The key of the dictionary must match exactly. I changed the case for the demo.*

Output:

```
          Values≤Thr  Values>Thr
Column A           1           2
       B           0           3
       C           2           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another option:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column': [13, 7, 11, 12, 14, 14, 7, 8, 11]})
df.index = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']

thresholds = {'column':{'A':10,'B':11,'C':9}}

df['smaller'] = df['Column'].groupby(df.index).transform(lambda x: x < thresholds['column'][x.name]).astype(int)
df['greater'] = df['Column'].groupby(df.index).transform(lambda x: x > thresholds['column'][x.name]).astype(int)

df.drop(columns=['Column'], inplace=True)
# group by index summing the greater and smaller columns
sums = df.groupby(df.index).sum()

sums
```

[image]